# numpy.select - IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Using np.select, I am seeking to return index row of first value in df['price'] less than smallest value in df1['price'] above last value in df['averages']. However, when there are no rows in df1['price'] less than smallest value in df1['price'] above last value in df['averages'], instead of returning 'NaN', I get the following error: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Here is the code that I have constructed

```
shop = {'price': [90.5, 82.4, 81.6, 71.2, 56.9]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(shop, columns = ['price'])

month_data = {'averages': [75.1, 72.0, 68.4, 52.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(month_data, columns = ['averages'])


conditions = [
              (np.abs(df1['price']-df['averages'].iloc[-1])).argmin() == len(df1) - 1, # index row of smallest 'price' value above last 'averages' value == df1 length minus 1
              (np.abs(df1['price']-df['averages'].iloc[-1])).argmin() < len(df1) - 1, # index row of smallest 'price' value above last 'averages' value < df1 length minus 1
              ]

results = [
              'NaN', # return 'NaN' if index row of smallest value in df['price'] above last df['averages'] value is equal  to df1 length minus 1
              df1[df1['price'].lt(np.abs(df1['price']-df['averages'].iloc[-1])).argmin()].index[0] # return index row of first value in df['price'] less than smallest value in df1['price'] above last value in  df['averages']
           ]

price_idx = np.select(conditions, results, default='')
```

How can I return 'NaN' instead of the error when index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: can you provide an MRE?

Comment: @ombk sorry i do not know what a MRE is, please can you clarify

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Either check the size of the arguments before passing them to `select`, or wrap the `select` in a standard `try/except` block

Comment: @hpualj please can you provide an example